# Looking for the name of algorithm for turning around keys and values in specific hashes

Tags: algorithm, naming

UPDATE : Let me elaborate to the closers : I am asking for the name of a routine.
I try to honour the [Principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) and naming is very important.

Besides : if this is an existant routine, and my guess is it is, there *is* an *objective* name for it.  When I know this name I could, to name just 1 thing,google on it.

I need to 'turnaround' a hash in javascript as shown here.  (the values are always arrays).  The function `turnaround()` is not the problem (I have written it already) but the name is.

What Am I doing here exactly, or put differently has this routine a name?

If it isn't a well-known algoritm, how should I name it so that the name defines what it's doing?

```
true == ( (h2 == turnaround(h1)) && (h1 == turnaround(h2))


h1 : {
    a : [ 2, 3 ],
    b : [ 3, 4 ],
    c : [ 2, 4 ],
    d : [ 1, 5 ] }

h2 : {
    1 : ["d"], 
    2 : ["a","c"], 
    3 : ["a","b"], 
    4 : ["b","c"], 
    5 : ["d"] }
```

Comment: "invertHash", I suppose. But honestly, why does it matter what you name your own functions?

Comment: There's no such thing a 'own functions' for me, I try to write reusable.  IMHO naming functions is extremely important.  A function should do only 1 thing and the name should tell as precise as possible what that is.

Comment: Besides InvertHash would mean to me switching keys and values, and a good example of how bad naming can be misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, if you have a map associating keys with lists of values, the corresponding mapping from values to lists of keys is called an **[inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index)**.  Since what you are doing is constructing the inverted index for a particular mapping, you could call your function something to the effect of `createInvertedIndex` or `invertIndex`.

Comment: Yep,this is what I was looking for.  I knew it had to exist.  I even need the same set calculations as in the text-search example.  My feeling was right to ask for it, tx!

Answer (score 1):

Your function is such that turnAround(turnAround()) = Identity .

turnAround = turnAround^-1

when applying turnAround(h) you find the unique element h^-1 such that h = turnAround(h^-1)

therefore you've inversed h. ([inverse function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function))

You can call it **inverseHashFunction** ?

I think it's explicit enough,

otherwise **reciprocalHash** ?  **reciprocalBijectionHash** ? etc...

Comment: Inverting a hash means to me : switching keys and values, in this case, the keys would become the arrays rather.

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can think of your hash as describing a relation R, according to the definition that x R y if and only if y is in `h1[x]`.

Then, the return value of your `turnaround` function describes the inverse relation in the same way: by definition y R<sup>-1</sup> x if and only if x R y. That happens if and only if x is in `turnaround(h1)[y]`.

So, if you're actually using `h1` and `h2` as descriptions of relations, then I'd call it `invertedRelation` or similar. If you're not using them as descriptions of relations (or you are using them as that, but the mathematical term 'relation' isn't familiar to your readers), that might just be confusing.

What kind of variable names do you really use for these hashes? If you're fanatical about function names being descriptive, surely you don't really call your variables `h1` and `h2`!

Comment: I am far from fanatic, but of course no, h1 and h2 are for the sake of the example.

Comment: But I want to see it more generic than the h1 and h2 cases, so how I call them here is of no importance imho.

Comment: @Peter: I think you should have some name for what a hash of this form actually is, and I expect deciding on that name will probably help name functions that operate on them. So it is potentially important - if hashes of this form are referred to in documentation as "foobars", and the names of variables containing them are typically "leftFoobar", "rightFoobar, "userFoobar" and so on, then it would be a good idea to call the function "reversedFoobar" or "invertedFoobar".

Comment: That's true, but that's not the case here, like I said, it has to be generic.  As an example :  I was looking for the 'Reverse()' in Array.Reverse().  For me it has to work in all contexts so no Array.FoobarReverse.